# Using PHP to display dynamic image depending on variable in function

Tags: php

I have a file called test.php which contains the function

```
function product01(){
    $product01 = "Chair";
    echo $product01;
}
```

I would like to use test.php to control what image is displayed in my index.php file. The path to my images folder is /images/products/ and this contains all my products.

If `$product01` is equal to "chair" I would like  `<img src="/images/products/chair.jpg">` to be displayed.
If I change it to "book", I would like `<img src="/images/products/book.jpg">` to be displayed.

Comment: Have you made an attempt? What seems to go wrong? It seems that you can [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) the value into your image tag and use [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to make it lower-cased.

Comment: So basically you want to use `test.php` as the image URL?

Answer (score 3):

In order for you to do something like this, you need to return the correct headers and echo the image into the response. Here's an example (not tested but should work):

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="image.php?image=chair" />

</body>
</html>
```

**image.php**

```
<?php

$image = file_get_contents('images/' . $_GET['image'] . '.jpg');

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo $image;
```

Comment: Excellent script, and excellent job at reading the asker's mind.  l too want to do this.  Very useful.  Should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you search for a loop to chek the value name of img and redirect it like this

```
   function product($productname){
       if($productname == "Chair"){
         return '<img src="/images/products/'.$productname.'.jpg">';
      }
    }
```